# Sheet name as a SUB parametr vs VLOOKUP

Tags: excel, vba

I am quite new to VBA, could someone please help?

I have folowing code and I would like to call it from different subs in different sheets → so I gave SHEET_NAME as a parametr of this sub, however, this can not work with vlookup, at least not this way. Can someone propose different way how to do this? 
BTW I do not need the formula in the cell, I am perfectly fine just with value.

```
Sub ART_R(FROM_CELL, TO_CELL, SHEET_NAME)

Range(FROM_CELL).Select

    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],SHEET_NAME!C[-12]:C[-11],2,0)),"""",(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],SHEET_NAME!C[-12]:C[-11],2,0)))"

Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(FROM_CELL, TO_CELL), Type:=xlFillValues

End Sub
```

Thanks a lot!

EDIT:
now it looks like that:

```
Sub ART_R(FROM_CELL, TO_CELL, SHEET_NAME)
    Range(FROM_CELL).Select
    ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],"&SHEET_NAME&"!C[-12]:C[-11],2,0)),"""",(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],"&SHEET_NAME&"!C[-12]:C[-11],2,0)))"
    Selection.AutoFill Destination:=Range(FROM_CELL, TO_CELL), Type:=xlFillValues
End Sub
```

The call should look (ideally) like that:

```
Call ART_R("M4", "M19", "RPL OC")
```

where "RPL OC" is name of sheet - it will be always different

Comment: One thing I can see without testing is that your passed sheet name contains a space, but you're not taking that into account in  your formula.  `,'" & SHEET_NAME & "'!C[-12]` would work.

Comment: It does not show the compile error anymore, so we do have little progress, haha. However, every time the sub is called, new window opens with question "where to save". So I guess it thinks, that the "SHEET_NAME" is actuall name of some sheet, not String variable..

Comment: whole the formula is in " ", it is inserted into cell like it is.. Isnt that the problem?

Comment: Yes, part of the problem is probably positioning of the `" "`.  I think my answer below will solve it.

Comment: Your edited code works as long as you put the extra `'` in around the `Sheet_Name`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This will place the formula in each cell between `From_Cell` and `To_Cell` on `Sheet_Name`.

I see you're using `=IF(ISERROR.....` in your code - this is the way to do it in Excel 2003 and earlier, after 2003 `IFERROR` is better.

2007+ version:

```
Sub Test()

    Art_R "O2", "O23", "RPL OC"

End Sub


Public Sub Art_R(From_Cell As String, To_Cell As String, Sheet_Name As String)

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet_Name)
        .Range(From_Cell & ":" & To_Cell).FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=IFERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'" & Sheet_Name & "'!C[-12]:C[-11],2,0),"""")"
    End With

End Sub
```

2003 version:

```
Public Sub Art_R(From_Cell As String, To_Cell As String, Sheet_Name As String)

    With ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets(Sheet_Name)
        .Range(From_Cell & ":" & To_Cell).FormulaR1C1 = _
            "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'" & Sheet_Name & "'!C[-12]:C[-11],2,0)),"""",VLOOKUP(RC[-1],'" & Sheet_Name & "'!C[-12]:C[-11],2,0))"
    End With

End Sub
```

Comment: It works, I love you! :D 
I missed the extra ' in the code..

Thank you so much :)

Answer (score 0):

```
Call ART_R(FROM_CELL, TO_CELL, Application.Caller.Worksheet.Name)
```

and in your sub:

```
ActiveCell.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(ISERROR(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],"&SHEET_NAME&"!C[-12]:C[-11],2,0)),"""",(VLOOKUP(RC[-1],"&SHEET_NAME&"!C[-12]:C[-11],2,0)))"
```

Comment: It shows → Compile error: Expected: end of statement